# Tool to recognize text in Image and edit it and create new image with edited text

Tags: image, image-processing, ocr, edit

Hi is there any tools which do the following steps:

1. Recognize Text in image
2. Edit the text
3. Create new image with ne text

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, this is very difficult (especially for a picture).

You need a good OCR.

The OCR needs to be able to recognize the exact font.

If the background isn't a solid color, the OCR will be perturbed and possibly not able to extract the exact characters and erase them correctly.

But also, if there is a background, when you change the characters you need to reconstruct the background where characters have been erased.

Then the editor needs to paint the new text with the same rendering attributes (size, italics, outline...), which may be a difficult task.

Because of this complexity, the best option is often to do it by hand.